Причастие со сравнительным оборотом. Пунктуация
Необходима ли запятая перед сравнительным оборотом, если он связан с причастием?
Но больше всего меня поразил его нос, торчащий (,) словно клюв хищной птицы.

Спасибо,  Анна,  за вопрос,  пришлось подумать)
ТЕОРИЯ

И вот мой ответ: нет,  это нежелательно. Возможность  удаления сравнительного оборота из предложения не может быть надежным критерием его обособления, поэтому можно получить неверный ответ.  Для каждого конкретного случая нужно проводить собственный анализ структуры, то есть определять грамматику и расстановку пауз и ударений.  Общего решения здесь быть не может, а структурных вариантов много. Но это несложно, просто нужен опыт решения базовых стандартных задач.

А что же является критерием при решении? Пожалуй, исходная позиция для любого трехчастного оборота, который потенциально всегда имеет два решения: (1) обособление как основной вариант и (2) отсутствие обособления при обстоятельственном значении.

Так, оборот нос как клюв без обособления является грамматическим сочетанием (связь примыкание) и произносится без паузы как единая фонетическая фраза. Это свойство должно сохраняться во всех синтаксических конструкциях. Возможна замена: торчащий клювом.


ПРАКТИКА
Обособление сравнительного оборота
Вариант 1.
Конь повернул к ней острую, как клюв, мОрду и потянулся к ее 
рукам губАми. 
Конь повернул к ней острую морду  / и потянулся к ее 
рукам губАми.

Оборот не относится к структуре предложения, а уходит на второй план речи. Если его убрать, ничего не изменится. Но вот на что обратим внимание:  само определение не обособлено, поэтому предложение не совсем по теме (в заданном предложении обособленное определение). Обстоятельство можно убрать, это попутное (художественное) сравнение.
Вариант 2.
 Я долго любовался его лицОм,  // кротким и ясным, / как 
 вечернее нЕбо.
 Я долго любовался его лицОм,  // кротким и Ясным.

В обоих случаях предложение состоит их двух частей, хотя  исходное предложение графически (запятыми) делится на три части. По интонации основная пауза перед определительным оборотом, но сам оборот дополнительно делится произносительной (меньшей)  паузой  на две части. Если убрать оборот, структура и интонация заметно не меняются, но оборот обособлен.
Вариант 3.
Но больше всего меня поразил его нос, торчащий, словно клюв 
хищной птицы.
Но больше всего меня поразил его нОс, торчАщий…

Здесь структура аналогичная, но оборот нельзя убрать, а почему?
Вариант 4.
Я долго любовался его лицОм,  // ясным, / как вечернее нЕбо.
Я долго любовался его лицОм,  // ясным…

Тоже нельзя убрать оборот? Вот и делаем вывод: дело в том, что в таких предложениях сложно обособить одиночное определение в постпозиции (структура получается неуравновешенной).
Вариант 5 (для сравнения)
 Но больше всего меня поразил его нОс, // торчащий как 
 клЮв.

Нет обособления для союза КАК?   Также:
  У Брызгалова было сухое, морщинистое буро-красное лицо, с 
  крючковатым, узким как клЮв, синеватым носом. 

В этих предложениях словосочетание со связью примыкания для союза КАК, что практически невозможно для союза СЛОВНО (у  Розенталя эти союзы рассматриваются отдельно от союза КАК). Оборот имеет обстоятельственное значение.
Нет обособления распространённого сравнительного оборота
 Пианист уронил подбородок на гАлстук,  // торчащий как 
 крылья белой бАбочки,  // и положил пальцы на клАвиши.

Уникальное предложение с интересной структурой: сложный оборот относится к одному из однородных сказуемых, связанных союзом И.
 Пианист уронил подбородок на галстук  / и положил пальцы на 
 клАвиши.

Предложение простое, в нем одна произносительная пауза, а ударение уходит в конец предложения. Если добавить сложный оборот, он весь находится на втором плане речи, поэтому разделить его на две части хотя бы произносительной паузой не получится. Поэтому и нет обособления сравнительного оборота: это единая фонетическая фраза, хотя и сложная.

Спасибо за правку, вот как здесь без вас)

Благодарю за столь подробный и аргументированный ответ!

ВМЕСТО ВСТУПЛЕНИЯ
— Всегда ли распространенный сравнительный оборот в составе причастного оборота должен обособляться?
— Конечно!
— А вот и нет! Встретилось мне тут интересное предложение:
Н. Н. Шпанов. Музыкант (1941-1942). 
Пианист уронил подбородок на галстук, торчащий как крылья 
белой бабочки, и положил пальцы на клавиши

А оборот как клюв обособляется и без зависимых слов:
Валентин Распутин. Последний срок (1970) 
Конь повернул к ней острую, как клюв, морду и потянулся к ее 
рукам губами.

ОТВЕТ
Правильно: Но больше всего меня поразил его нОс,  торчАщий,   словно клюв хищной птИцы.
Пояснение

Рассмотрим исходную конструкцию: Его нос торчИт, словно клюв хищной птИцы.

Трехчастная конструкция: нос — клюв — торчит, сравнение двух предметов через действие. Обособление как норма, но возможно и обстоятельственное значение. Проверяем ударением: два ударения, на сказуемом и на обороте.
При переходе к причастию расстановка ударений не меняется: два ударения, сравнительный оборот обособляется. Это в какой-то мере стандартная задача.
В то же время в предложении основная (грамматическая) пауза делается перед причастным оборотом,  а сравнительный оборот выделяется  только произносительной паузой и меньшим ударением. Соответственно, могут возникнуть  вопросы относительно его обособления.

Интонационный анализ при решении подобных задач исключительно важен: можно ориентироваться на правила, на примеры, но проверить сложные решение можно только интонацией.

Примечание. С другой стороны, хорошее чувство языка и практический опыт тоже хороши. Собственно говоря, интонационный анализ дополняет и развивает такое чувство. Ну и позволяет что-либо доказать и обосновать.

Тем не менее общую картину иметь совсем неплохо, и поэтому я добавлю практический материал по теме.

СРАВНИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ОБОРОТ в составе обособленного определения
(1) ОБОСОБЛЕНИЕ определительного оборота
В состав обособленного определительного оборота может входить обособленный сравнительный оборот:
Цветы глядят с тоской влюблённой, безгрешно чисты, КАК 
ВЕСНА.
Я долго любовался его лицом, кротким и ясным, КАК ВЕЧЕРНЕЕ 
НЕБО.
На самом дне, сухом и жёлтом, КАК МЕДЬ, лежали огромные 
плиты глинистого камня Пили бабушкины наливки — жёлтую, КАК 
ЗОЛОТО, тёмную, как ДЁГОТЬ, и зелёную 

(2) Определение, содержащее сравнительный оборот, НЕ ОБОСОБЛЯЕТСЯ:
Определение не обособляется, если оно является смысловым центром:
Ночь хмурая, КАК ЗВЕРЬ СТООКИЙ, глядит из каждого куста.
Перстами лёгкими, КАК СОН, моих зениц коснулся он. 

(3) Сравнительный оборот может не обособляться, если он является фразеологическим:
Наконец он закончил потрошить диван и обрушился вниз, 
злобный КАК ЧЕРТ.
Сравнить: Наконец он закончил потрошить диван и обрушился 
вниз, злобный, КАК СОРОК ТЫСЯЧ ОС.

Также возможна следующая запись стиха Пушкина: Перстами, 
лёгкими КАК СОН, моих зениц коснулся он.

(4) Авторское решение (два варианта):
Чувства, ЧИСТЫЕ И СВЕТЛЫЕ, как первый снег, переполняли его 
душу (обособленное определение).
Чувства ЧИСТЫЕ И СВЕТЛЫЕ, как первый снег, переполняли его 
душу (определение не обособляется).

Авторское решение возможно, если структура предложения допускает два варианта прочтения. Всё определяется возможностью перенести ударение с определяемого слова на определение и сделать его центром высказывания (тогда определительный оборот не обособляется).

Я отбрасывала сравнительный оборот, которому предшествовала запятая, в различных примерах, и смысл предложения при этом не менялся: "Я долго любовался его лицом, кротким и ясным", "Конь повернул к ней острую морду и потянулся к её
рукам губами" и т. д. Но если в моём предложении удалить данную конструкцию, то получится нечто недосказанное: "Но больше всего меня поразил его нос, торчащий". В приведённом вами примере из "Музыканта" тоже нельзя опустить сравнительный оборот без потери смысла. Может ли безболезненное отбрасывание сравнительного оборота быть критерием постановки запятой?

Нужна, потому что сравнение распространённое.
Было б только "нос, торчащий словно клюв", то есть клювообразно, обошлись бы без запятой, но "хищная птица" портит всю малину, и потому:
Но больше всего меня поразил его нос, торчащий, словно клюв хищной птицы.
